# .htaccess file add special character after redirect

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have dashes in my query string, after redirect from .htaccess file dahes changed into %252d pls check below mention htaccess rule

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /hotels-details\?hotelcode=(\S+)&hotel_key=(\S+)&hnm=(\S+)&hct=(\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /hotel/%3-in-%4-%1-%2? [R=301,L,B]
RewriteRule ^hotel/(.*)-in-(.*?)-(\d+)-(\d+)/?$ /hotels-details/hotelcode=$3&hotel_key=$4&hnm=$1&hct=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `B` flag and use it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /hotels-details\?hotelcode=([^\s&]+)&hotel_key=([^\s&]+)&hnm=([^\s&]+)&hct=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /hotel/%3-in-%4-%1-%2? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^hotel/([^-]+)-in-([^-]+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/?$ hotels-details/hotelcode=$3&hotel_key=$4&hnm=$1&hct=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: We just change server its shown error like: Request exceeded the
limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use
'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel
debug' to get a backtrace. pls help